# Convert sql script to eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

recently I am using PHP Laravel with PostgreSQL and I don't know how to convert this sql script to eloquent.

```
SELECT v_extensions.extension, 
( 
    SELECT COUNT(v_xml_cdr.uuid) FROM v_xml_cdr WHERE v_xml_cdr.extension_uuid = v_extensions.extension_uuid AND start_stamp >= @startDate AND end_stamp <= @endDate
) 
FROM v_extensions ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1
```

I am trying to do something like this, but I don't know how can I write that `extension_uuid` from XmlCdr is equal to `extension` from Extension. Also these columns are not linked by foreign key on database.

```
$call = Extension::select('extension', function(){
        XmlCdr::where('extension_uuid', )
    })->limit(10)->get();
```

found it a way how to do it with `DB::select`

```
$query = 'SELECT v_extensions.extension, (SELECT COUNT(v_xml_cdr.uuid) FROM v_xml_cdr WHERE v_xml_cdr.extension_uuid = v_extensions.extension_uuid) FROM v_extensions LIMIT 1';
$result = DB::select($query);
```

Comment: Why don't you use `\DB::raw()` instead?

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar I did something like this `        $all = DB::table('v_extensions')->select('extension, (SELECT COUNT(v_xml_cdr.uuid) FROM v_xml_cdr WHERE v_xml_cdr.extension_uuid = extension_uuid AND start_stamp >= @startDate AND end_stamp <= @endDate)')->get();
` but its throwing an error there where i am using the dot ('.')

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar did it with DB::select()

Answer (score 0):

First, Eloquent is an ORM. To use it you'll have to create Model(s) which extend the Eloquent model [model docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models) and define the relationships on them
[relations docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Assuming you did it, you should have something like this:

```
class ExtensionCDR extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = "uuid";      // primary key column name
    protected $table      = "v_xml_cdr"; // by default Eloquent assumes your table has the same name as the class - more or less

    // add relations like
    public function extensions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Extensions::class); //further parameters may needed - see docs
    }
}

class Extensions extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
     protected $table = "v_extensions";

     // add relations
}
```

With this you can do this (anywhere basically):
(I'm not sure about which table has the relevant timestamps)

```
// this is the case where the timestamps are on the related model
$result = ExtensionCDR::whereHas('extensions', function ($query) use($start, $end) {
    return $query->whereDate('start_stamp', '>', $start)
                 ->whereDate('start_stamp', '<', $end);
})->get();
```

I understand that this won't be a perfect (copy/pasta) answer, but I hope it will steer you in the right direction; 
In case I misunderstood you completely, just use the Database module with raw queries like so: [raw things](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Yes but inside that $query->whereDate() it shoud be another one where('extensionId',EXTENSIONID from ExtensionCDR model). And I don't know how to type that EXTENSIONID from ExtensionCDR

Comment: that part is handled by the relation, it is defined with that fkeys and they are used by default; basically by using the `whereHas` the foreign key restictions are inserted by dewfault in the background